# Update column in row - column_1 = column_2

Tags: android, sqlite

I added one column to my table with:

```
ALTER TABLE dn_car_repair_options ADD option_id INTEGER
```

Now this table has next DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
node_id INTEGER, 
name VARCHAR,
car_id INTEGER DEFAULT (0),
option_id INTEGER);
```

And I want UPDATE all rows where (row1)**option_id** = (row1)**id**

Can I make this using SQLite?

Comment: This is simple update: `UPDATE dn_car_repair_options SET option_id = id`.

Comment: lad2025 please write as answer - its work!

Comment: TIL: SQLite ignores VARCHAR size SQLite does not impose any length restrictions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating new column use simple [`UPDATE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

```
UPDATE dn_car_repair_options 
SET option_id = id;
```

Without `WHERE` clause it will affect all rows in table.